# Como incluir arquivo .jsp na solução?

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, servlet

Estou a desenvolver aplicações web Java usando JSP's. Eu tenho um arquivo chamado `header.jsp`, que contem links dos arquivos CSS's e outras coisas que são importantes para o meu sistema que está no diretório raiz.

Eu tenho uma pasta que tem outros arquivos `.jsp`, mas quando eu tento fazer um arquivo de inclusão `header.jsp`, não funciona.

Comment: Lucas, seja bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português, se você for brasileiro sinta-se a vontade para perguntar em português =)

Comment: @LucasNascimento, o que você quer dizer com "quando eu tento fazer um arquivo de inclusão `header.jsp`, não funciona"? Você não está conseguindo incluir o `.jsp` em outro?

Comment: Eu consigo fazer o include se o arquivo estiver no mesmo diretório, mais se ele estiver em um diretório diferente eu nao consigo.

Comment: Sem descrever o problema na pergunta vai ser muito difícil alguém conseguir te ajudar. Apenas dizer que não funciona não dá informações suficientes para as pessoas ajudarem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Então, vamos supor que você queira incluir o `header.jsp` dentro de um arquivo chamado `clientes.jsp` (você não especificou o nome, então eu inventei um para poder exemplificar). Há basicamente 4 formas de se fazer isso:

---

## Alternativa 1: Diretiva include

É só usar o seguinte no `clientes.jsp`:

```jsp
<%@ include file="header.jsp" %>
```

Isso daí vai copiar-e-colar o código do `header.jsp` no `clientes.jsp` antes de compilá-lo para um servlet java. **A inclusão ocorre em tempo de compilação.**

---

## Alternativa 2: Standard action jsp:include

Você usa desta forma no `clientes.jsp`:

```jsp
<jsp:include page="header.jsp" />
```

Isso daí vai fazer o servlet compilado do `header.jsp` ser invocado de dentro do servlet compilado do `clientes.jsp`. **A inclusão ocorre em tempo de execução, quando a requisição está sendo processada.**

É possível passar parâmetros no `jsp:include`:

```jsp
<jsp:include page="header.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="teste" value="Parâmetro de teste" />
</jsp:include>
```

No arquivo `header.jsp`, você pode pegar o valor do(s) parâmetro(s) usando EL:

```jsp
${param.teste}
```

---

## Alternativa 3: Tag c:import da JSTL

Esta outra alternativa, é semelhante a forma usada com a standard action:

```jsp
<c:import url="header.jsp" />
```

O `<c:import>` permite você importar até documentos externos ao seu container de aplicação:

```jsp
<c:import url="http://example.com/header.jsp" />
```

E também pode usar parâmetros:

```jsp
<c:import url="header.jsp">
    <c:param name="teste" value="Parâmetro de teste" />
</c:import>
```

No arquivo `header.jsp`, você pode pegar o(s) valor(es) do(s) parâmetro(s) usando EL, exatamente da mesma forma como ocorre com a standard action:

```jsp
${param.teste}
```

---

## Alternativa 4: Tagfiles

Esta forma é a mais complicada, porém é também a mais flexível, robusta e poderosa. Você pode colocar o arquivo `header.tag` dentro da pasta `WEB-INF/tags`. Observe que a extensão do arquivo é **tag** e não **jsp** neste caso.

Então, no seu `clientes.jsp` basta você colocar isso no começo:

```jsp
<%@ taglib prefix="meuProjeto" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
```

E lá no meio, aonde você quiser colocar o cabeçalho:

```jsp
<meuProjeto:header/>
```

Se quiser passar um (ou mais) parâmetro(s), use assim:

```jsp
<meuProjeto:header teste="Tagfiles são legais"/>
```

E lá no seu arquivo `header.tag`, você coloca isso no começo:

```jsp
<%@ attribute name="teste" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" %>
```

E no mesmo arquivo `header.tag`, você resgata o(s) parâmetro(s) com estas expressões EL extremamente simples:

```jsp
${teste}
```

O `required` especifica se o atributo é requerido ou não (opcional). O `rtexprvalue` indica se o valor será avaliado em tempo de execução quando a requisição estiver sendo processada ou não.

Observe que ao usar tagfiles, o resultado fica semelhante a uma chamada de função, aonde você diz quais parâmetros são requeridos ou não e o código do `clientes.jsp` para incluir o `header.tag` fica super enxuto e simples. Além disso, os parâmetros ficam definidos com um escopo estático (não-dinâmico), o que facilita bastante para o desenvolvedor ao evitar problemas de ter que adivinhar o nome do parâmetro ou de o mesmo colidir com o nome de outra coisa e também forçam um erro se um parâmetro requerido for esquecido ou se um parâmetro inexistente for usado.

Se o conteúdo do parâmetro for muito grande, você pode declarar um corpo para ele. Para fazer isso, coloque o seguinte no início do seu `header.tag`:

```jsp
<%@ tag body-content="tagdependent" %>
```

E para interpretar o corpo:

```jsp
<jsp:doBody/>
```

No `clientes.jsp` você invoca desta forma:

```jsp
<meuProjeto:header teste="tagfiles sao legais">
    Este é um exemplo de uma tagfile aonde é usado um corpo bem grande.
    Lorem ipssum dolor sit amet consectetuer adispiting elit.
</meuProjeto:header>
```

O corpo da tag é interpretado quando o `<jsp:doBody>` é invocado, ele não é apenas copiado e colado, e sim é uma forma de um lambda em JSP. Logo, você pode fazer isso:

```jsp
<meuProjeto:header teste="tagfiles sao legais">
    <c:if test="${variavelQualquer == 1}">
        O valor da variável é 1.
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${variavelQualquer == 2}">
        O valor da variável é 2.
    </c:if>
</meuProjeto:header>
```

Para finalizar, você pode colocar os seus arquivos `tag` dentro de qualquer subpasta de `WEB-INF/tags`, e normalmente só isso já basta. Alternativamente, é possível colocá-los dentro de pastas `META-INF/tags` de JARs que estejam dentro do `WEB-INF/libs`, mas neste caso você vai precisar acrescentar um arquivo TLD e fica um pouquinho mais complicado.

---

Fonte: Livro "Head First Servlets & JSP" de Bryan Basham, Kathy Sierra e Bert Bates. Usei a primeira edição, que já é antiga e ultrapassada (de 2004), mas ainda assim é muito boa e recomendo bastante.